# How to print a week in date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use sql server.
what I've been doing is this:

```
LEFT(yearmonth,4) + RIGHT( '0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(WK, yearmonthdate)), 2)
```

yearmonth = '201601'

and

yearmonthdate = '20160101' through '20160131'

which prints out like this:

```
201601
201602
```

but I want to print out like the following:

```
20160101-20160102
20160103-20160109
```

respectively.

How do I accomplish that? 
I've on google but I couldn't get to print out like that.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add sample data as well. Also tag the DBMS you are using

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Some how stackoverflow should enforce users to tag the DBMS they are using before posting the questions

Comment: @Prdp It is explicitly stated in the tagging recommendation in `sql` tag to mention the DBMS. The problem is people do not read the instructions and guidelines.

Comment: Sorry, people. I added the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Col1 INT, Col2 DATETIME)
DECLARE @StartDT DATETIME
DECLARE @tempDT DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDT DATETIME
SET @StartDT  = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()),MONTH(getdate()),1)
SET @EndDT  = EOMONTH (@StartDT)

set @tempDT=@StartDT

WHILE @StartDT <  @EndDT
BEGIN
PRINT 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR,cast(@tempDT as date)) 
     +  ' - '   + 
     convert(VARCHAR,cast(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @StartDT)), @StartDT) as date))

SET @StartDT    =   DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @StartDT)), @StartDT)
SET  @tempDT = DATEADD(dd,1,@StartDT)
SET @StartDT    =   DATEADD(WEEK,1,@StartDT)
END

PRINT   
     CONVERT(VARCHAR,cast(@tempDT as date)) 
     +  ' - '   + 
     convert(VARCHAR,cast(@EndDT as date))
```